# Wrong pip3 python location

Tags: python, version

I'm in Ubuntu / Linux

I try to install python3.8.2 with the latest version.

before i install i had Version 3.5.2, and that works very well.

but now pip and pip3 is the same linked location:

```
pip -V
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
pip3 -V
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

the problem is why i can't install any packages with the new version error message says:
**

> sudo pip3 install nltk

**

```
WARNING: The directory '/home/fredy/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting nltk
  Downloading nltk-3.4.5.zip (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB 2.3 MB/s 
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-d0mx8gb1/nltk/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-d0mx8gb1/nltk/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-d0mx8gb1/nltk/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-d0mx8gb1/nltk/
    Complete output (11 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/fredy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import Distribution
      File "/home/fredy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 34, in <module>
        from setuptools import windows_support
      File "/home/fredy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
        import ctypes
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
        from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

**(pip list)**

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        20.0.2 
setuptools 46.1.1
```

**(pip3 list)**

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        20.0.2 
setuptools 46.1.1
```

**step1:**

> how can i come back to python3 with pip3. ?

**step2:**

> how can i fix the error so i can work with 3.8.2 ?

What will you do ? :)

**Thanks for your time** !